# How to delete from database after tests insert data using PHPUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, continuous-integration, phpunit, tdd

I want to delete every new entry made with the tests in order to make it possible to run it again (both on the CI build or manually) without having to manually delete the database entries made with the previous run of the tests. I have found the `tearDown()` and `tearDownAfterClass()` but it seems to be useful only for connecting/disconnecting the link with the database. Can I use it to delete the entries made with the tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to delete every new entry made with the tests in order to make it possible to run it again (both on the CI build or manually) without having to manually delete the database entries made with the previous run of the tests.

In set-up create an online snapshot of the database and in tear-down reset it to the snapshot point.

Whatever your tests have done to the data in the database or to the structure of it, it is not part of the snapshot which ran before the test and therefore gone.

Please consult your DBA about the options for the database system in use and you might want to bring in a system administrator as well, as it might be possible this is most easily done with a snapshot feature of the file-system and you would be interested to integrate this all with your test-suite.

Comment: That seems doable. Any idea how that'd work out using SQL Oracle?

Comment: Not with SQL alone, but check your Oracle docs, it should have related SQL commands in there. Also these kind of questions are better addressed to your database administrator (DBA) as that person is normally more knowledgeable about the specifics of your database. Depending which database (as in instance, not vendor) you're using there might be constraints in testing and the DBA can normally discuss them with you (this is not a technical issue).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it via the methods you mentioned.

- `tearDown` method is enabled after every single test inside the class
- `tearDownAfterClass` method is enabled at the end of all tests inside the class

I would suggest you use a rollback pattern, so

- in the `setUp` method you would initialize the transaction

```php
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        //...some boilerplate with establish connection
        $this->connection->beginTransaction();
    }
```

- in `tearDown` method you would rolling back changes made in tests

```php
    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        $this->connection->rollback();
    }
```

Comment: Problem with rollback is that the changes are already committed, so I don't think it'll work. And it has to be this way because I need to test if the methods actually do write in the dB. Any tips?

Comment: If the amount of data is manageable you may rollback manually in tearDown(), i.e. write DELETE statements for the INSERTs done in testing. It is not as nice and generic, but still an option.

Comment: @Masamune you can easily check it in your assertion method if data exists in the database. Please have a try this solution, I think it would be enough for you. This pattern comes from the "xUnit Test Patterns: Refactoring Test Code" book. If you want take a look at the example in PHP by searching "teardown rollback phpunit"